# Verify the app origin

Tags: android, security, google-play, apk

I'm developing a paid app and i have some doubts. As i know, some programs can download paid app for free from play store...and i want to check it. Can i:

- Verify if the app was installed directly from play store?
- Verify if the app is already on the user app list from play
- Block the app if it was installed from another origin instead of play store?

Searching on the developer android...i found some informations about licensing (http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html). Is that the way?

Comment: Licensing is the way to go but you can stop your efforts if your app is worth the effort to reverse engineer and crack. You are basically guaranteed that one talented person will do it. And from that point on people just need to google "[app name] apk".

Answer (score 2):

You should implement Licensing, so downloaded app still would need to call home to see if it was really bought or not. Sure, you still can be cracked/hacked/reverse engineered, but at least just downloading will not work any more.

See docs: https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You may also cosider implementing ProGuard. It scrambles your code so that if someone decompiles the apk file, all the methods and classes will be renamed to something that is very had to read and follow. It will slow down the hacker considerably.

**EDIT** - It will also remove all comments from the compiled apk, so all the methods and classes will be virtually impossible to follow and hard to work out their purpose.

See here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html